# Good program to cut out image regions manually

Tags: software-recommendation, gimp, image-processing

I have to process several hundred images manually. The work consists of cutting out square regions from the pictures. I want to save these regions. When saving, there should not be any loss of quality. The old image can be overwritten when saving. Which program is suitable to do this task quickly?

Comment: You might try posting this question on Software Recommendations https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com or maybe have a moderator move it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Gimp for that purpose:

- open image with Gimp
- r key for rectangle select
- select with mouse
- ctrl+c for copy
- shift+ctrl+v for paste as new image
- shift+ctrl+e for export as...

I like Gimp because it has keyboard shortcuts for everything and combining keyboard with mouse makes typical tasks quick and effective.

Comment: Is there also a shortcut to select a square region?

Comment: I doubt it. Try posting on some Gimp forum.

Answer (score 4):

Gimp, using the Crop tool. You can set the Crop tool to **Fixed: aspect ratio** with dimensions **1:1** and save that as a default

**Edit > Preferences > Save tool options > Save tool options now**

or save it until you reset it:

**Edit > Preferences > Save tool options > Save tool options on exit**

If you need to process many images in sequence, the [`ofn-file-next` script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) will do the *Save current image, Close current image, Open next image* in one operation (one keystroke if you make a shortcut for it).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are looking for something that can automate the process instead of doing it manually.

[ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) is generally well-suited for this kind of tasks. It has a command line interface that can do a lot of things.

For your kind of task, check [this link](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) under "Inline Image Crop". That should do what you want to achieve.